# How to Make Scite Display Chinese

Tags: notepad, utf-8, chinese, scite

Basically not just chinese characters.

I want scite to be able to display anything, japanese, korean, chinese. Anything. I can display that with notepad. Why I can't display that with scite?

Answer (score 1):

SciTE v2.23 on Windows seems to work fine with these character sets for me. Have you set the encoding to UTF-8?

`File -> Encoding -> UTF-8`

**Additional:**

According to the SciTE [documentation](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTEDoc.html) section on Encoding:

```
SciTE will automatically detect the encoding scheme used for Unicode files
that start with a Byte Order Mark (BOM). The UTF-8 and UTF-16 encodings are
recognised including both Little Endian and Big Endian variants of UTF-16.

UTF-8 files will also be recognised when they contain a coding cookie on one
of the first two lines. A coding cookie looks similar to "coding: utf-8"
("coding" followed by ':' or '=', optional whitespace, optional quote,
"utf-8") and is normally contained in a comment.
```

Comment: Ah I see. How do I arrange so that scite figure that out from the file?

Comment: @Haryanto, please see the additonal info I have added to my answer.